# Корректно удалить невидимую кнопку на Wordpress сайте

Tags: html, wordpress, веб-сайт

Сделал свежий сайт на Wordpress, заметил то, чего никогда не замечал: если нажать Tab на клавиатуре, выскакивает кнопка (слева сверху, "Перейти к содержимому"):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Кнопка ведёт по ссылке mySite.ru/#main, т.е. скролит на метку main моего сайта, которой я даже не делал. Как я понял, табуляция перебирает активные элементы сайта, и самый первый из них невидимый, но при фокусе показывается. Могу заблуждаться, в сайтах шарю очень мало.

Пожалуйста, помогите понять природу этой кнопки, и как полностью и корректно удалить её с сайта, а не просто замаскировать.

(При разработке использованы: PHP 8.0, WP 6.0, Elementor поверх OceanWP темы)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кнопка "перейти к содержимому" фича последних версий WP. Может быть убрана прописыванием следующего кода (ниже) во внешний вид > настроить > Custom CSS:

```
a.screen-reader-text.skip-link {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Это не убирание, а скрытие. Переход по TAB никуда не денется и по ссылке можно перейти нажатием энтер.

Comment: SeVlad, сам удивился, но она вообще исчезла. Хром обычно показывает в левом нижнем углу сылку в фокусе (в том числе, если фокус взят через TAB). И вот после добавления указанного мной в ответе кода, я слежу через ссылку в фокусе, и там стало на одну табуляцию меньше. Всё исчезло! :)

Comment: Почти согласен, был вчера не совсем прав (не внимательно посмотрел код). Однако первое предложение в силе. А вообще этого делать не нужно. Погугли для чего применяется skip-link.